# Laravel : Service provider for methods

Tags: php, laravel, provider

I'm building a php class which need for some methods a Request instance.

**Example :**

```
static public function warningAlert($message, Request $request) {
    $request->session()->flash('alert-warning', "$message");
}
```

I thought that the service provider will provide this instance but he dont :

```
Argument 2 passed to ...\validatorAlerts() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given
```

How can I provide him ?

**PS : I don't wan't to use facades.**

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
app()->call('Classname::warningAlert', [ $message ]);
```

Alternatively you can modify your method:

```
static public function warningAlert($message) {
    $request = resolve("request");
    $request->session()->flash('alert-warning', "$message");
}
```

Comment: So there's no way to provide an instance to a method ? Why can I in some controller so ?

Comment: @ThomasPetillot there's the classical `warningAlert($message,resolve(Request::class))`. The reason the controller works is because at some point the framework is doing something similar to `app()->call` after it resolves the route handler.

Comment: Do you know where I can found specify information about the scope of the app call ?

Comment: @ThomasPetillot not sure I've understood the question but overall the [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container) is a good read about what's going on here. I'm sure there's also a laracast somewhere about it that goes more in depth.

Comment: Sorry for my english, I will try to deepen my research, thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1):

You can use the helper function `request()`

```
static public function warningAlert($message) {
    request()->session()->flash('alert-warning', "$message");
}
```

Or even better, I do recommend you to use the [`laracasts/flash`](https://github.com/laracasts/flash) package

Comment: Thanks for the package, that's exactly what I'm doing ! Anyway, I steel want to found an answer to the original question :-)

Comment: @ThomasPetillot have you tryied `request()` to get an instance of the current request ?